# How can I indicate that empty elements of a matrix are zero?

Tags: matrices, transition-matrix

I have the following transition matrix in an academic conference paper:

$$\mathbf{P}=\begin{bmatrix}
1-p & p   &       &        &         &      \\ 
        & 1-p & p &        &         &      \\ 
        &         &       & \ddots &         &      \\ 
        &         &       &        & 1-p & p\\ 
        &         &       &        &         & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

What is the best way to indicate that the empty elements are zero? I could also add a description in the body of the text. I considered something like "the off-diagonal elements are zero", but there are nonzero elements off of the diagonal so this wouldn't be entirely accurate.

Comment: It's the usual convention that omitted matrix entries are zero.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That was my understanding but I've received reviewer comments regarding it so I wasn't sure if there was an alternative.

Comment: If you want to make it clearer, maybe you can add large zeroes like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69459/upper-triangular-matrix-with-big-zero-in-lower-triangular)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- One simple way: mention $P$ is [bidiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidiagonal_matrix).

  > Let $\mathbf{P}$ be the $n\times n$ bidiagonal matrix
  >   $$\mathbf{P}=\begin{bmatrix}
  > 1-p & p   &       &        &         &      \\ 
  >         & 1-p & p &        &         &      \\ 
  >         &         &       & \ddots &         &      \\ 
  >         &         &       &        & 1-p & p\\ 
  >         &         &       &        &         & 1
  > \end{bmatrix}$$
- Another: write it (semi) explicitly by adding a big zero to indicate blocks identically zero (this is quite standard).

  > Let $\mathbf{P}$ be the $n\times n$ matrix
  >   $$\mathbf{P}=\begin{bmatrix}
  > 1-p & p   &       &        &         &      \\ 
  >         & 1-p & p &        &     \Large 0    &      \\ 
  >         &         &       & \ddots &         &      \\ 
  >         &    \Large 0     &       &        & 1-p & p\\ 
  >         &         &       &        &         & 1
  > \end{bmatrix}$$
- A third: combine both.

  > Let $\mathbf{P}$ be the $n\times n$ bidiagonal matrix
  >   $$\mathbf{P}=\begin{bmatrix}
  > 1-p & p   &       &        &         &      \\ 
  >         & 1-p & p &        &     \Large 0    &      \\ 
  >         &         &       & \ddots &         &      \\ 
  >         &    \Large 0     &       &        & 1-p & p\\ 
  >         &         &       &        &         & 1
  > \end{bmatrix}$$

Note: to be even more specific, you can write "upper bidiagonal."